# how to store and use variable in pig

Tags: apache-pig

i have a tuple stored in A:

```
{group: chararray,word_count: long}
```

so, I sum all word_count variable, and store it in a variable T:

```
T: {long}
```

now, I have a variable X that looks like:

```
(word1,12,word1,1)
(word2,22,word2,4)
(word3,32,word3,14)
```

I need to do math operation on 1, 4 and 14 against the value stored in T,
but my for each doesn't recognize T.

```
result = FOREACH X GENERATE $3*T;
```

It fails. It doesn't recognize T, because there is no field called T in X.

so, what i did is, i cross the X and T
    temp =  CROSS X, T

is this the correct way?? I'm new to pig. My solution, doesn't seem to be very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way you have chosen is about the best way to do this.  Pig doesn't have a concept of standalone variables.  What you think is a single variable, `T`, is actually a relation that just has a single tuple with one field.  Pig operates one record at a time, and if a piece of data isn't available in that record, or in an internal parameter (something defined by `%DEFAULT` or a command line parameter), then you can't use it.

The one amendment I would make to your approach is that using `CROSS` will read in the two relations, perform the cross-product, and then write that back out to disk.  This is a waste of resources.  Instead, you can use `JOIN` and take advantage of the special directive `USING 'replicated'`.  This instructs Pig to store the second relation in memory and do the join in the map phase, rather than sending the data to reducers, doing the join, and writing it to disk.

`temp = JOIN X BY 1, T BY 1 USING 'replicated';`

Joining by the dummy value `1` makes the `JOIN` equivalent to a `CROSS`. `USING 'replicated'` puts `T` in memory so it can be done in the map phase and thus combined with adjacent MR jobs.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I'm a beginner in PIG and hadoop. any good book you recommend maybe?

Comment: Check out the O'Reilly book Programming Pig.